# Getting SQL Error: ORA-28576: lost RPC connection to external procedure agent

Tags: linux, oracle

I am getting "SQL Error: ORA-28576: lost RPC connection to external procedure agent" error when i was trying to execute and external procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You need to play with `SQLNET.INBOUND_CONNECT_TIMEOUT` option, Try to increase timeout value default is 60 seconds.

Comment: where can i find this SQLNET.INBOUND_CONNECT_TIMEOUT option

Comment: sqlnet.ora : The sqlnet.ora file typically resides in $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin on UNIX platforms and %ORACLE_HOME%\NETWORK\ADMIN on Windows operating systems.

Comment: it still dint work..it was initially 3 i changed to 100 but still not working